# Issue with adding fields in Views 3.7

Tags: views

I'm having an issue with Views 3.7 not displaying all fields in the 'add field' dialog when trying to add a field to a view. There is only a small number of fields available from nodes etc whilst on my development version (which is almost identical) there are loads of fields to choose.

I have tried to copy my development version database to use on the staging version and use that but I get the same problem. Flushed caches etc.

Another related problem is when you try to add a custom header to your view, there are no selections to choose from. Click on close, and you get a page full of JSON.
I am unsure where to go on from here. Anyone had a similar issue in the past? Thanks.

Comment: could you have a different version of jQuery on the staging server ? the views edit form doesnt play nice wit newer jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Views uses a lot of JavaScript, also AJAX to get latest info from the server. I had a similar problem a long time ago but that was because my Drupal instance was on my localhost and that gave errors with AJAX requests.

Answer (score 0):

Disable views data caching, located in ...->Structure->Views->Settings->Advanced

I got the solution from https://drupal.org/node/1954348#comment-7280942